# How to add indexing for a search based on multiple columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am adding a search button with the suggestions displayed while we type on it similar to google and I need to search multiple columns in a single table. How to add indexing for that columns?

I have two tables in my application named as `Employer` and `Employee`. I want to add a search box so that the Employer can search employees of only his organisation based on their name or email or phone number. When the employers types on the search box I need to show the suggestions below. For Ex. when employer types `Jo` on the text box, I will show suggestions as

**1. Jon, jon@gmail.com, 12345**

**2. Bobby, jon-bobby@gmail.com, 9876**

**3. .....**

The Employee table has columns `id, name, email, phone, employer_id fk references Employer` table.

What I think the query might be is

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
where employer_id = 1 
and LOWER(name) like '%jo%' 
or LOWER(email) like '%jo%' 
or LOWER(phone) like '%jo%'
```

I want to know whether this is a valid query to use. I am not sure about its performance. Also I am not sure how to add index to this table in this particular use case.

I would really appreciate your valuable suggestions.

Comment: A suitable `COLLATION` is usually better than using `LOWER` or `UPPER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to increase performance you can do the following:

Add FULLTEXT index to the columns name, email and phone

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD FULLTEXT (name), ADD FULLTEXT (email), ADD FULLTEXT (phone)
```

Dont use select * ( no caching )

`select name, email, phone
, (
  10 * (MATCH (name) AGAINST ("Jon*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
+  8 * (MATCH (email) AGAINST ("Jon*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
+  2 * (MATCH (phone) AGAINST ("Jon*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
) as points 
from Employee HAVING points > 1 
order by points DESC LIMIT 10`

In this solution you get an result in a better order of your results.
If your keyword match with name, it is more helpfull to show than a match with phone.

You can change your my.cnf and add: `ft_min_word_len = 3`to index words up to 3 chars.

Comment: This fails when an email search is made i.e when we use @ character. Do you know how we can resolve this?